# How to write a wrapper class in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, wrapper

I writing simple wrap app that one get the a)Request Date & Time of the user request
b)Request URL.
c)Response Time.

This is How to wrap the express js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var appget = app.get;

(function() {

app.get = function() {

  var start = new Date();

  console.log('arguments', arguments)

  var result = appget.apply(this, arguments);
  var end = new Date();

  var duration = end.getTime() - start.getTime();

  console.log("duration===", duration);
}

})();
```

I wrote simple the wrapper code
But need to know how to get the req parameters ?

Anybody experience in this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Express middleware functions placed before all of your routes so you can apply this across any routes to your server. In the middleware, The below code is waiting for the [`'finish'` event to be emitted from the `res` object](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_finish), once the headers and body have been fully written to be sent back to the requester. If you prefer to log the response time once the request itself has been closed you could listen for the [`'close'`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_close_2) event on the `req` object instead in the middleware below.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

// Place this middleware before any of the route definitions/middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // store when request date & time came in
    req.startTime = Date.now();

    // Log the original URL requested
    console.log(req.originalUrl);

    // Register finish event handler so when the response
    // body and headers are sent, the total responseTime is logged
    res.on('finish', () => {
        let responseTime = Date.now() - req.startTime;
        console.log(`Response Time: ${responseTime}`);
    });

    return next();
});

// Place all routes/router middleware here  

app.listen(port, () => { 
    console.log(`Listening on ${port}); 
});
```